# Sending an array as json Flask to React.js

Tags: reactjs, opencv, flask

I am using flask as a backend as a server for OpenCV's facial detection module. I cannot seem to access the x and y coordinates of the face and send them to the react.js front end. I am new to the flask, this is the error I am receiving:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

I believe this is because the flask server is not sending readable JSON to react.js, but I am sure I am doing other things improperly. I am wondering how exactly I can save data into an array and send it to react in a JSON format.

camera.py:

```
import cv2
import json
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

class VideoCamera(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
  #must delete webcam otherwise the webcam will become "trapped" and you cannot use it for other apps until the computer restarts
  def __del__(self):
    self.video.release()
    
  # geting the frame and converting it to jpeg format
  def get_frame(self):
    success, frame = self.video.read()
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
      cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
      break #exit loop after rendering one face
    
    ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    return jpeg.tobytes()

  def get_axis(self):
    success, frame = self.video.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    axisArr = []
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
      axisArr = [x,y,w,h]
      break #exit loop after rendering one face
    
    return json.dumps(axisArr)
```

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../../frontend/src')

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def setAxis(axisGen):
    global axis
    axis = axisGen
    
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        axisGen = camera.get_axis()
        setAxis(axisGen)
        # creates html render template
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
  
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame') #explains the type of response the html is receiving and sending it to the browser

@app.route('/members')
def members():
    return {"members": axis}
  
# initialize the server to run the flask app on, debug mode means you do not need to close and reopen the server to see changes
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port='4999')
```

Comment: try using `jsonify` from flask controllers

Comment: When you get to this kind of problem, you probably want to debug things (print the variable, print the variable type, etc) and have a better idea of what the problem may be. As @ShivaGaire mentioned, jsonify is usually the way to go to serialize things in Flask.